# want to execute onload event only five times in a day

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

Dear all, I am facing problem in execution of onload even for fix number of time.

Actually my requirement is : I have to show a rating script to every single user untill he/she did not rate it. But condition is that, this script has to shown only five time in a day not more than that and this should not shown to user over life time once he get rated it. Showing of script 5 times(1 time per page load) in a day will be continue...till is is not rated...

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: keyboard! i guess...@RayonDabre :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the browser's localstorage to keep track of how often you have shown it to a user on this day and if the user has already rated.

The concrete implementation obviously depends on what exact behavior you expect.

Comment: thanks for reply..Florian.. Actually I need to show a rating script only five times in a day untill it is not rated by user....once it get rated...it should not shown over life time...I am just trying to do it on a jsp ...can you give me a example code for the same...hope you understand me...